# Column Name in Pivot table is a day Need to group by month

Tags: excel, pivot, sumifs

Good Morning,

New user here; need assistance please. My data is structured with days across a spreadsheet.  t1 = 9/30/2016, u1 = 10/1/2016, v1 = 10/2/2016 etc...

The right side of the sheet s1:s711 has structured data which are the specific employee numbers i.e. 5672291. These are unique identifiers and do not repeat.

The data contained between t2:bsa711 represents the amount of sales on a given day for the employee.

I have tried several sumifs and sumproduct functions to capture the amount of sales for each employee by month. This did not work due to the multiple criteria (employees name and <= EOMONTH => EOMONTH criteria to sum the sales within the month)

My last attempt has been to pivot the data and group by month, but I am unable to produce the desired result because I can only get column names (the days) in the pivot list (1000+ due to the T-BSA range of columns/days).

My overall goal is to know the total per month I am not averse to using pivot or some type of array sumifs. Sorry that I do not have much to add to show research. I have been looking.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You'll have to unpivot your data first. What Excel version are you using?

Comment: The data is not pivoted. Excel 2013. I am attempting to use a pivot the solve my problem. The raw data is in a spreadsheet like described. Thanks for reading.

Comment: The data is in a shape that is similar to a pivottable, hence the need to unpivot it first. Have you got access to PowerQuery (PQ)? If so, this is as easy as Clicking the From range/Table button on the PowerQuery tab of the ribbon and then on the transformation tab of the PQ window you select Unpivot other columns and finally return this data to Excel and create the pivottable and group your dates.

Comment: I believe my version only has powerpivot

Comment: You can download PowerQuery (or activate in your Com add-ins if it is already there)

Comment: Sorry.. don't have install rights

Comment: In that case we'll use the old Pivottable wizard. 1. Right-click the QAT, select "Customize Quick Access toolbar". 2. From the choose commands drop down select commands not in the ribbon. 3. Scroll down to the P and click on "PivotTable and pivotchart wizard". 4. Add it to the QAT. 5. Close dialog and click the new button. 6. Choose "Multiple Consolidation ranges", press Next. 7. Choose "Create a single page field for me" and click Next. 8. Now select your data and click Add and click Next and click Finish. 9. Finally. double-click on the grand total.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dates are formatted as dates.

Click on analyze -> insert timeline-> select column for dates.

You might want to experience with slicer and pick the days you want which is even more specific.